# Mark grouped posts as read or unread mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a system in php that users can create many posts with images and other users can see this grouped posts by clicking in the autor's name.

When user1 post a new thing, user2 will see it as new (the user1's name will have an underline indicating it has a unseen post inside). And that is my problem, to know if user2 has seen all user1's posts or not.

```
select c.user, count(v.id)

from posts s 

join cadastro c on s.user=c.id 
left join posts_view v ON v.posts_id = s.id

group by s.user
order by s.id desc limit 20
```

I tried this count v.id to check if user2 has seen a post, but user1 may had created many posts and I need to know if user2 seen all of them. any ideas how to do this?

my tables:

posts:

```
 `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `foto` varchar(400),
  `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20),
```

posts_view

```
 `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `posts_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, //foreign key to posts id
  `user` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, //the user who saw the post
```

How to know if an active user has read all posts of an user or not?

Comment: Add some sample data and DDL so others can use that to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT distinct(P.user) 
 FROM posts_view PV
 JOIN posts P ON P.id = PV.posts_id
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM posts_view 
                   WHERE posts_view.user = userID 
                   AND posts_view.posts_id = P.id)
```

Hope this helps.